# There are 70's, 80's and 90's, how do you describe the years from 2000 (00's)?

Tags: word-request, pronunciation, dates

We sometimes describe the years between 1970-1979 as "seventies" (written as 70's), 1980-1989 as "eighties" (written as 80's) and so on.

- What is the equivalence in describing 2000-2009, 2010-2019 and so on?
- I came across the written terms "00's". If it is a valid written term to describe 2000-2009, how is it spoken?

Comment: Look it up on Wikipedia, it's all there

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000s_(decade)#Name_for_the_decade and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BrE (and AE, apparently), the years 2000-2009 are often called *the noughties*, especially by the British media (*nought* = *zero*). See the link provided for pronunciation. Personally, I detest it and always use "the two thousands".

[Cambridge Dictionary: noughties](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/noughties)

[Cambridge Dictionary: nought](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nought)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Regarding 2009-2019, is it something like the "tens"?

Comment: I have to confess that I don't know (or can't remember). [hangs head in shame] ;-)

Comment: Apparently, it's *the tenties*. If I knew who makes these things up, I'd shoot them (or lock them up and force them copy the entire 20 volumes of the OED in copper-plate handwriting).

Comment: It is indeed an odd name, and Cambridge Dictionary doesn't even include the word! As this decade is mid-way over, I really hope it got a proper name in history

Answer (score -3):

From 2000 to 2009 the 10's
From 2010 to 2019 the 20's
From 2020 to 2029 the 30's
From 2030 to 2039 the 40's
From 2080 to 2089 the 90's
From 2090 to 2099 the. 100's

And starts all over...
But we are referring about a different millenium, and when we started again about the same millenium but another century.

Now, we are in centyry XXI. And that's because we've already wasted part of the next century 2016 (left 83 years 2months and a few days  one second after 20100 would be century XXII)
The same with the decades 10years and one secund we start wasting the 11th which is part of another decade so we are beginig a new one.

Comment: I think we deserve an explanation.

Comment: One decade 10 years.  One century 100years, one millenium 1000years . We are in XXI. And thats because

Comment: But the nineteen-tens were 1910-1919. I think you've got them out of step.

Comment: When we are in XXII is going to be 2100 and start again with the decades

Comment: The first 10 years wasted are the 10's and so..

Comment: Is this an accepted usage, and if so, where? Or is it just your own system?